# Executable made with pyinstaller doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I've tried to create an executable of my python script with pyinstaller, but it's not working.

If I run the exe file from terminal, I get these errors:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 127, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 9, in main
  File "c:\users\danie\onedrive - universitat de valencia\escritorio\professors banda\profs\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "docx2pdf\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "importlib\metadata.py", line 531, in version
  File "importlib\metadata.py", line 504, in distribution
  File "importlib\metadata.py", line 177, in from_name
importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: docx2pdf
[13776] Failed to execute script main
```

I installed pyinstaller using pip inside the virtual environment of the project.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have missing modules, that weren't found by PyInstaller analysis hooks.

Try to rebuild your application with `--hidden-import=docx2pdf` option.